# Determine when a the current user account's password is about to expire

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, active-directory, passwords

I am trying to write some code to check the AD password age during a user login and notify them of the 15 remaining days and finally force them to change if it's less than 5 days.

I don't know how to access the days remaining.

The PC's are on a domain. The Policies are set for account password expiration to occur on 90 days.
Users are warned 15 days before account password expires. Users can still ignore the message but my application would pester them until they change their password

Comment: There seems to be lot of articles on this one. Did you search?

Comment: Yes but not knowing what you're looking for is harder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did a quick Google Search and was able to come up with this [How to get Password Expiration Date with System.DirectoryServices (C#)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alejacma/archive/2008/03/25/how-to-get-password-expiration-date-with-system-directoryservices-c.aspx)

Comment: What kind of class or object is ActiveDs.IADsUser native = (ActiveDs.IADsUser)entry.NativeObject;?